# Generate locale of all currencies in iPhone

Tags: iphone, locale, currency, symbols

I want generate array of all locales for all International currencies. I want to display the array of currency symbols , so user can select any one. To generate the currency symbol i need the locale of all the International currencies. Please any one guide me to generate array of currencies locale.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Get an array of all available locale identifiers with `[NSLocale availableLocaleIdentifiers];`
2. Loop over the array and create an `NSLocale` instance for each locale id.
3. Get the locale's currency symbol with `[locale objectForKey:NSLocaleCurrencySymbol];`.
4. Insert the currency symbols into the data structure (array, dictionary) you need for further processing.

Comment: Thanks, for many locale the the symbol generated is ¤, how to resolve this

Comment: That's the universal currency symbol, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currency_(typography). I'd say that many currencies either don't have a currency symbol or that Foundation doesn't include them.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
NSArray* currency = [NSLocale availableLocaleIdentifiers];

for (int i = 0; i < [currency count]; i++) {
    NSLocale *locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:currency[i]];
    NSString *currencyCode = [locale objectForKey:NSLocaleCurrencyCode];
    NSString *currencySymbol = [locale objectForKey:NSLocaleCurrencySymbol];
    NSLog( @"Code: %@ Symbol %@", currencyCode,currencySymbol );
}
```